# Pre-select parent item in many2one popup

Tags: python, odoo, many-to-one, openerp-8

Let's start with a basic One2many relation, a class **Parent** and a class **Child**.

Models :

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    _name = 'module.parent'
    child_ids = fields.One2many('module.child', 'parent_id')

class Child(models.Model):
    _name = 'module.child'
    parent_id = fields.Many2one('module.parent')
```

Views :

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="parent_form_view">
        <field name="name">parent.form</field>
        <field name="model">module.parent</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Parent Form">
                <sheet>
                   <field name="child_ids" />
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="child_form_view">
        <field name="name">child.form</field>
        <field name="model">module.child</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Child Form">
                <sheet>
                   <field name="parent_id" />
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

When I open a **Parent** form and try to create a new **Child** from the one2many popup, the `parent_id` field is not selected with the current open **Parent** from the window view !
I have to retrieve it in the `parent_id` selection field to re-select it.

Is there a way to do this autoselection ?

Comment: How did you solve this finally? I have the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    _name = 'module.parent'
    child_ids = fields.One2many('module.child', 'parent_id')

class Child(models.Model):
    _name = 'module.child'
    parent_id = fields.Many2one('module.parent')
```

You have defined same model name in parent and child class.

Comment: It was just a typing mistake, edited in original post.